# Reverse for 'get_post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'sample-post'}' not found

Tags: python, regex, django, url, reverse

I am using django 1.9. While implementing class based views and urlpatterns I am not able to redirect my particular link to corresponding post.

**settings/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from posts.views import Home


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^post/', include("posts.urls")),
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name="blog_home"),
]
```

**posts/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import Display


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', Display.as_view(), name="get_post"),
]
```

**posts/views.py**

```
class Display(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        params = {}
        params['post'] = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)        
        return render(request, "blog/viewpost.html", params)

    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

and my error follows:

[error is shown in that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w595.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the url regex `r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$`, the `\w` matches alphanumeric characters and underscore. It will not, however, match hyphens `-`.

So, when your template looks for a URL with `slug` equal to `sample-post`, the above regex will not find a match. You should try using this instead:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', Display.as_view(), name="get_post"),
]
```